# Why is it hard to steer My car when I drove through puddles?

Tags: steering

Why does the power steering misfunction when I drive through puddles? W ill it be ok when it dries out? I have a Chevy Prism.

Answer (score 5):

If you have one of the early models with a "V" belt the most likely cause is a slipping power steering belt. The belt may be just loose or it may need to be replaced. If it has been slipping for awhile just tensioning the belt may not be enough. When the belt slips for a long enough time it overheats and develops a glaze that slips even when properly tensioned.